# Ruby on Rails routing problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The company that hosts my website did an upgrade on the weekend and now all my ROR apps are coming up with this :

Routing Error

No route matches "/geotest/" with {:method=>:get}

These were working before and do work on my development system, but there has been no response to my ticket to their tech support. Anyone got a suggestion how I could fix this?

Comment: BlueHost.com, usually they are more responsive.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe they upgraded to Rails 3 ? Your route should work anyway, but try to add this to your routes.rb file :

```
get '/geotest' => 'your_controller_name#index'
```

Change your_controller_name accordingly, of course.

Comment: If they updated your Rails to Rails 3 "for you", I would find a new host.

Comment: well, they have to do it sometime i suppose. It's that Rails follows the principle "change everything if something better comes up". However, i think that the vast majority of stuff would work from Rails 2 to 3, including routes.

Comment: Why do they have to do it at all? (hint: they don't)

Comment: They  upgraded to 2.3.11, not 3. Adding the line above resulted in :   "Application error Application failed to start properly"

Comment: ohh, if it's not 3, then this route will not work, it's for rails 3.

Comment: Rein, i'm pretty sure there are also security fixes in Rails 3. A host has to be updated. It's actually a shock to me that they still use 2.3.11. They should at least give a choice for 3.